# How to get only the website url without the absolute path of the current site collection?

Tags: workflow, url

I have a custom workflow in VS. I would like to merge an url. The problem is I am in an site collection with the name RFC. I see the absolute path 2 times when I merge like below:

```
ItemURL = currentItem.ParentList.DefaultDisplayFormUrl + "?ID=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(currentItem.ID.ToString());



string finalUrl = workflowProperties.WebUrl + ItemURL;

This results: http://mywebsite.nl/sites/RFC8/sites/RFC8/Lists/Wijzigingsverzoeken/DispForm.aspx?ID=1
```

The problem is, you see 2 times the absolute path : sites/RFC8

Here you can see what the merge is doing:

```
http://mywebsite.nl/sites/RFC8/ + sites/RFC8/Lists/Wijzigingsverzoeken/DispForm.aspx?ID=1
```

How can I get the website url without absolute path? Something like this: http://mywebsite.nl/

Comment: Isn't ItemURL enough? Because normally a Server-Relative URL should do... (if you want to pass it via mail or else, there is the UrlMapping in the WebApplication-Class, which can be used)

Comment: No, ItemURL is returning only: sites/RFC8/Lists/Wijzigingsverzoeken/DispForm.aspx?ID=1

Answer (score 1):

You have already stored a server relative url in the ItemUrl variable.

```
// this returns "sites/RFC8/Lists/Wijzigingsverzoeken/DispForm.aspx?ID=1 "
ItemURL = currentItem.ParentList.DefaultDisplayFormUrl + "?ID=" 
             + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(currentItem.ID.ToString());
```

The SPSite object offers a method called [MakeFullUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsite.makefullurl.aspx) that *"Returns the full URL for the specified server-relative URL"*. That means that you only need a valid SPSite instance to be able to call the aforementioned method and obtain the full url you need.

You can use the [Site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/microsoft.sharepoint.workflow.spworkflowactivationproperties.site.aspx) property from the workflowProperties object or, for a more general approach, just reuse the currentItem instance you already have. So, for example you can use:

```
string finalUrl = currentItem.ParentList.ParentWeb.Site.MakeFullUrl(currentItem.ParentList);
```

Just a final notice: as pointed out by this blog post ([link](http://www.novolocus.com/2010/05/25/getting-absolute-urls-in-sharepoint/)), MakeFullUrl **DOES** take in account Alternate Access Maps. Most of the time this is exactly what you want, but sometimes it could be a problem. If that is the case, please ensure that you use a SPSite that has been constructed from an url relative to the specific access map you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
workflowProperties.siteurl
```

or

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath
```

=

```
ItemURL = currentItem.ParentList.DefaultDisplayFormUrl + "?ID=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(currentItem.ID.ToString());

string finalUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath + ItemURL;
```